# Picking...with json and ray

Tags: three.js

Sorry for the English. How can I access the mesh of a model loaded with Json to pick? I need to access parts of the model and paint the parts that
are the mouse over.
I use this code below:

```
var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

        var intersects = ray.intersectScene( scene );


        if (intersects.length) {

            if ( INTERSECTED != intersects.mesh ) {

                if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                INTERSECTED = intersects.mesh;
                INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );  
                INTERSECTED = mesh.geometry.material;
            }

        } else {

            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

            INTERSECTED = mesh.geometry.material;

        }


        webglRenderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: Does this example help you? http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html

Comment: I am using this example, but not intersect the color is going to object loaded.

Comment: Can you provide a very simple live example to demonstrate your issue? Please use the simplest json model you can.

Comment: I resolved this by using MeshLambertMaterial. When the mouse hovers on top of what I select an object, the object's color is changed.